# Custom DrawItem ListBox Delphi don't draw last row icon

Tags: delphi

I have a custom DrawItem implemented and it works fine with every item aside the last item. This is my function:

```
procedure TFrameBusquedaAvanzada.lstBusquedaListaDrawItem(Control: TWinControl;
  Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var lGrafico:TIcon;
begin
  lGrafico:=nil;
  with lstBusquedaLista,(Control as TListBox).Canvas do
  begin
      lGrafico:=TIcon.Create;

      FMain.imageList.GetIcon(TClassCarpeta(Items.Objects[Index]).Icono,lGrafico)
      TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left+Margins.Left+24,Rect.Top+6,(Control as TListBox).Items[index]);

      if Assigned(lGrafico) then
      begin
        StretchDraw(System.Classes.Rect(Rect.Left,Rect.Top,Rect.Left+24,Rect.Top+24),lGrafico);
        FreeAndNil(lGrafico);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Unless the last item is selected or I do a scroll in the ListBox, the icon won't be shown.

Comment: It's ListBox, I did a mistake...

Comment: I don't have a PC nearby so i can not test this code, but a few tips:
Remove this line:
    lGrafico:=nil; //Also why don't you make this a global variable, and create/free it just once
Also this:
    StretchDraw(System.Classes.Rect(Rect.Left,Rect.Top,24,Rect.Top+24),lGrafico)

Comment: @SkyFlyer Global variable? Are you sure that's a good idea? Don't we normally want to avoid globals.

Comment: That's true, but that may not be the best choice in this case.
Because, what if he has >50 items, that's a lot of redrawing of the items in the list, meaning a lot of creating and freeing of instances of TIcon.
That's why I think it's better to just create/free it once.

Comment: Why not just create TIcon before while loop and destroy it after the while loop. This way you avoid creating and freeing TIcon in every while loop cycle. You can still asign its icon data the same way you do it now.

Comment: @SkyFlyer: The code uses a different icon based on the `Index` that it receives as a value. There's no loop here, so the icon is being created once. (The `lGrafico := nil;` and `if Assigned(lGrafico)` could both be removed, because `lGrafico` is never accessed before the `lGrafico := TIcon.Create;` executes, and after that it can never not be assigned (so there's no need to test `if Assigned`). The only optimization might be to just use `TImageList.Draw` to go directly to the canvas and eliminate the use of the TIcon completely.

Comment: @SilverWarrior: My thoughts exactly. Even though this is not a while loop. :D